# How can an internal direct sum of 2 abelian groups be a proper subgroup of one of the summands?

Tags: group-theory, modules, direct-sum

I have spent days now trying to understand the proof of an "easy lemma" in Martin Isaacs' book "Algebra: A graduate course".  The lemma is 11.10 on page 150, which reads the following:

> Let $N\subseteq M$, where $M$ is a completely reducible abelian $X$-group. Then $N$ and $M/N$ are completely reducible.

I understand the proof except for one small step, which reads as follows:

> Now $N=M \dotplus L$ for some $X$-subgroup $L\subseteq N$...

Recall that if $G=A \dotplus B$ is an internal direct sum, then $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$.  Internal direct products (and sums) always concern subgroups of a group.

My question:

Since the direct sum $N=M \dotplus L$ in the lemma is an internal direct sum, the summands $M$ and $L$ must be $X$-subgroups of $N$.  But it is $N$ which is a subgroup of $M$, not the other way round. So it makes no sense to me that you take the group $M$ and obtain from it a (possibly proper) subgroup $N$ by taking an internal direct sum.  How can an internal direct sum of 2 abelian groups be a proper subgroup of one of the summands?

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's probably a typo: $M=N\overset\cdot+ L$ should be written.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed,  what follows makes sense only if it was a typo. Thank you @Berci

Comment: Well, that's what 'completely reducible' means, right? By the way, what is an $X$-group?

Comment: @Berci  the book by Isaacs uses this terminology. An $X$-group $G$ is a group together with a set $X$ of endomorphisms. Isaacs introduces this concept on the way to introducing rings.